# Extra space between attributes and types in sqlite using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, syntax, scaffold

I was using rails to create a sqlite table in my application, I tried an example from a tutorial which I typed the command:

```
rails generate scaffold Product \
     title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

It worked and generated a table, however, when I ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

It came up some problem:

```
SyntaxError in ProductsController#index
products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...rams.require(:product).permit(: title, :description, :image_... ... ^
```

So I looked into the table and found that there's an extra space between title and string,
it's like this:

```
title : string
description :text
image_url :string
price :decimal
```

Then I changed it and the corresponding controller.
The controller was like this before I changed it, also an extra space here:

```
 def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(: title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
```

After that, whenever I tried to create a table, the same problem came again and again.
The first attribute always has an extra space while the following attributes don't.
So anyone knows what's the problem?
Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a tad late, but remove the `\` so that the rails generator looks like:

```
rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

The `\` is used to denote the end of a line in a multiline command and when you use it, hit enter to continue writing on the next line. (`^` on windows).

If you've already created the database you can rebuild it using:

```
rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal --force
```

If like me you found that code in Agile Web Development for Rails 4; the preceding paragraph explains the `\`.

Hope that small roadblock didn't push you away from rails all those months ago!